# For $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ find all directions in which exists $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}(\vec 0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

For $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, defined by:

$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2|y|+(x-y)^2+z^2}$ (for $\vec v\neq \vec 0$, and $f(\vec 0)=0$)

I need to find all directions in which exists $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}(\vec 0)$

The directional derivative is defined as (if exists. I'll address the right-side derivative first, for conveniance - so the absolute value won't complicate it too much):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}(\vec 0)=\lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(t\cdot\vec v)-f(\vec 0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{t^3x^2|y|}{t^3x^2|y|+t^2(x-y)^2+t^2z^2}= \lim_{t\to0^{+}}\frac{x^2|y|}{tx^2|y|+(x-y)^2+z^2}=\frac{x^2|y|}{(x-y)^2+z^2}=\frac{x^2|y|}{||\vec v||^2-2xy}=\frac{x^2|y|}{1-2xy}\iff x,y\neq\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt 2}$

So in any direction in the 3D ball other than the lines spanned by $\lbrace\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt 2}\left( \matrix{1 \newline 1 \newline 0} \right)\rbrace$

Am I right? I'm not at all sure about that... but if so, I guess the case for the left-side derivative is simillar.

Comment: @Alan are you sure? I checked it over a couple of times, the $t$ of the derivative formula's denominator seems to cancel it.

Comment: I was wrong, deleted comment

Comment: You do have to account for the other diagonal,  spanned by $\left( \matrix{1 \newline -1 \newline 0} \right)\rbrace$

Comment: @Alan You are right, thank you! Also, setting the $z$ coordinate as $0$ is a consequence of finding a unit-vector that satisfies the solution, right? This has nothing to do with leaving $z$ outside the final form of the derivative. I want to make sure my argument is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
\begin{align}
\frac{f(t\cdot\vec v)-f(\vec 0)}{t} &=   \frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{t^2|t|\,x^2|y|}{t^2|t|\,x^2|y|+t^2(x-y)^2+t^2z^2}\\ \ \\ &=   \frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{|t|^3\,x^2|y|}{|t|^3\,x^2|y|+|t|^2(x-y)^2+|t|^2z^2}\\ \ \\
&= \frac{|t|}t\,\frac{x^2|y|}{|t|x^2|y|+(x-y)^2+z^2}.
\end{align}
The second fraction converges to $\frac{x^2|y|}{(x-y)^2+z^2}$, but the first one will go to $1$ or $-1$ depending on whether $t>0$ or $t<0$. So the only way for the derivative to exist is that the second fraction is zero: that is $x^2|y|=0$, so either $x=0$ or $y=0$. We also need to account for the case where the denominator doesn't exist, which is when $x=y$ and $z=0$. So the allowed directions (without normalizing) are 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0\\ u\\ v
\end{bmatrix} ,
\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
w\\ 0\\ z
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Requiring that the above vectors are nonzero already accounts for the denominator case.

Comment: thanks! Suppose the original question was without absolute value at all, then my original solution would have been valid?

Comment: The restriction was stronger, $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, which got to those points

Comment: Alan is right, so i'm deleting my (wrong) comment.

Comment: @Martin Argerami just to make sure - $2xy\neq 1$ is still equivalent to infinitely many solutions, or since it is in terms of unit vectors - my solution (in the case of no absolute value) is good?

Comment: As Alan pointed out, the condition $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ (from $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$), gives only the two solutions $1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2$ and $-1/\sqrt2,-1\sqrt2$.